# How to I create multiple versions of one rails 6 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I've built a Rails 6 app that I want to 
a) keep improving
b) use for multiple different projects.

I've tried to work out how to do this.  One way seems the Engine route - eventually maybe I will go this route, but it seems like there is a lot to do and I want to start launching multiple projects now.

The only other thing I could think of is to have a separate git branch of each project, and perhaps use updates to the master to flow through to the other branches and the projects, but although I can't find anything that says "don' do that" I have a feeling it's because no-one imagined someone would even think of trying!

Are there any shortcuts to this?  I'm maintaining everything myself (the projects the app) and I just want to use what I've build in multiple ways whilst I carry on improving it!

Comment: You could fork the suspenders gem and change it to fit your needs as a sort of base project. https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders. Otherwise, you could make your base project, and pull that into your new project, then change the origin to the updated repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a base git repo and then fork it into multiple repositories. While this might save you some time at the present it may cost you time in the long run as you have to merge changes from the base application into the forks (and vice versa) and handle resolving conflicts in each fork.

In the long run using engines to share common features together with [application templates](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) in the way to go. With engines updating the "base" functionality of the apps can just be done by bumping the version in the gemfile.

Comment: Why would you create multiple repositories when you can use multiple branches?

Comment: @eikes because the apps might significantly diverge from each other and you might want to collaborate with others on one project but not on another project. Combine this with feature branches and having a dev and stable branch * number of projects and you have got big problems.

Comment: @eikes Admittedly this is less of a problem if your just building stuff for yourself  or if what your actually after is multitenancy but if you're building stuff for different clients your repo should not have a bunch of application code built for other clients in it if you have to turn it over. You should also consider what a god-aweful mess the git history will be.

Comment: might help if you use this gem ```https://github.com/jnunemaker/flipper```

Comment: I don't see how that would help with any of the code organization issues @tenzindorjee unless the applications are very alike in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said you can use a different git branch or you can use feature toggle pattern. Refer this link https://rubygarage.org/blog/separating-features-in-a-multi-tenant-saas-app.